# Android: how to create splash screen with text

Tags: android, android-activity, splash-screen

How can I add some text to splash screen? My splash screen isn't a separate activity and I don't want to make it as standard activity.

I created it by following this article:
https://android.jlelse.eu/launch-screen-in-android-the-right-way-aca7e8c31f52

Is it possible to add some text?

Comment: A [layer-list](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#LayerList) as used in your drawable, is a way to layer multiple drawables on top of eachother. You can not add plain text to the image, but you could define a new drawable which is the text, then add the layer to your list.

Comment: Use FrameLayout and add text on the top of image wherever you want.:)

Answer (score 12):

You can create a new `layout` for your splash screen. But if you still don't want to create it then there is a **nasty hack** to achieve it.

Open `Paint` write your text and save the file as `png` image

`Import` png file in drawables and add it in `<layer-list>` as an `item` below or above your logo/icon

`<item android:bottom="50dp">` set position as you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="50dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/myTextImage"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, I understood that there isn't any normal way to set text.

Comment: No **he shouldn't** create a new layout for splash screen. The point of splash screen is to provide some entertaining content while not slowing down startup of the application, and prevent that boring blank screen appearing. Inflating layout takes considerable time on Android, and **causes the blank screen to be visible before the layout appears**.