# How can I place white text on a black screen on Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Here's the XAML that I am using for a startup screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Test"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="40sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
            />
</layer-list>
```

I was hoping to see white text centered on a black screen.  The screen is black, but instead I cannot see any text appear at all.

Comment: Why is this a drawable mixed with a layout?

Comment: Because I am not sure how to put white text on a black background and found this example.

Comment: Don't mix a drawable with a layout

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you are trying to do.
You want to display a plain Text on your "Splash Screen" that displays when you open an app. Since you are using Xamarin, you have access to all the native API's and you can do everything that native developers can.

Unfortunately, being able to show plain text on the splash screen is not possible in native development. Android restricted it because "the view comes from the theme. When you set up the UI for your splash activity in the theme, it is available immediately".

Why can't I have plain text on the splash screen, when I can have images? As you see over [here in detail](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/), the splash screen only accepts drawable resources. And [there is no way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45621786/11104068) to convert plain text into XML drawable resources.

You do have another option though. You can use a "Loading screen". You can make the app show the splash screen, then a Loading screen, and then load the right page. Let me know if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Set background attribute to black. Either

```
android:background="#000"
```

or

```
android:background="@android:color/black"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to Xamarin in specific, but if you normally want to create some sort of splash screen for your activity, as far as I know, there is no way of directly adding a `TextView` to it, because [LayerList](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#LayerList) only supports bitmaps (image drawables) as child items. So you would have to  create an .img file containing your text. Then, you can add the image with the text to the `layer-list` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- This line below is for the background colour -->
    <item android:drawable="#000" />

    <item>
    <!-- The bitmap below contains the image with the text -->
       <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/my_text_on_screen"
        android:gravity="center" />

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

To see how to create an image from a text, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51110573/android-how-to-create-splash-screen-with-text) StackOverflow question.

Let me know of this is what you wanted to achieve! I hope this helps.